# Возникает ошибка в sql запросе после добавления условия

Tags: sql

не могу найти ошибку в своем запросе

```
                    $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `checks` WHERE `testlev`=1');
                    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        echo '<tr>' .
                            "<td>{$result['user_id']}</td>" .
                            "<td>{$result['famil']}</td>" .
                            "<td>{$result['Name']}</td>" .
                            "<td>{$result['testlev']}</td>" .
                            "<td>{$result['dattest']}</td>" .
                            "<td><a href='?red_user_id={$result['user_id']}'>Выбрать</a></td>" .
                            '</tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
```

Без "WHERE `testlev`=1" все работает исправно

Comment: А какая ошибка возникает, подскажете?

Comment: Только что решил вопрос, за кавычками не уследил. Спасибо!

Comment: думаю вы можете свой вопрос удалять)